# How to set the Cutomer Group when registering in magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer-group, register

I created 2 radio button in `newcustomer.phtml` and I created a new function in `Register.php`

```
public function postdata()
 {
     $radioVal = $_POST["Hello"];
     if ($radioVal == "male") {
           // set the group customer to local 
     }else {
            //set the group customer to export 
     }
  }
```

and according to the group name I will show a different form in `register.phtml` /.

```
if($block->postdata() == 'local')
{ 
   // show first form 
} 
else 
{
   // show another form 
}
```

so how to do that correctly and can you please give me some code to proceed this functionality. 
Here is the code of my `Register.php`

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Mweb\Inscription\Block\Form;

use Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement;

/**
 * Customer register form block
 *
 * @api
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 * @since 100.0.2
 */
class Register extends \Magento\Directory\Block\Data
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
     */
    protected $_customerSession;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager
 */
protected $_moduleManager;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Url
 */
protected $_customerUrl;
protected $groupRepository;


/**
 * Constructor
 *
 * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
 * @param \Magento\Directory\Helper\Data $directoryHelper
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Type\Config $configCacheType
 * @param \Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Region\CollectionFactory $regionCollectionFactory
 * @param \Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Country\CollectionFactory $countryCollectionFactory
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager $moduleManager
 * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
 * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Url $customerUrl
 * @param array $data
 *
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Directory\Helper\Data $directoryHelper,
    \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Type\Config $configCacheType,
    \Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Region\CollectionFactory $regionCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Country\CollectionFactory $countryCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager $moduleManager,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    \Magento\Customer\Api\GroupRepositoryInterface $groupRepository,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Url $customerUrl,
    array $data = []
)
{
    $this->_customerUrl = $customerUrl;
    $this->_moduleManager = $moduleManager;
    $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
    $this->groupRepository = $groupRepository;

    parent::__construct(
        $context,
        $directoryHelper,
        $jsonEncoder,
        $configCacheType,
        $regionCollectionFactory,
        $countryCollectionFactory,
        $data
    );
    $this->_isScopePrivate = false;
}

/**
 * Get config
 *
 * @param string $path
 * @return string|null
 */
public function getConfig($path)
{
    return $this->_scopeConfig->getValue($path, \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
}

/**
 * @return $this
 */
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('Create New Customer Account'));
    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}

/**
 * Retrieve form posting url
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getPostActionUrl()
{
    return $this->_customerUrl->getRegisterPostUrl();
}

/**
 * Retrieve back url
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getBackUrl()
{
    $url = $this->getData('back_url');
    if ($url === null) {
        $url = $this->_customerUrl->getLoginUrl();
    }
    return $url;
}

/**
 * Retrieve form data
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getFormData()
{
    $data = $this->getData('form_data');
    if ($data === null) {
        $formData = $this->_customerSession->getCustomerFormData(true);
        $data = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
        if ($formData) {
            $data->addData($formData);
            $data->setCustomerData(1);
        }
        if (isset($data['region_id'])) {
            $data['region_id'] = (int)$data['region_id'];
        }
        $this->setData('form_data', $data);
    }
    return $data;
}

/**
 * Retrieve customer country identifier
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getCountryId()
{
    $countryId = $this->getFormData()->getCountryId();
    if ($countryId) {
        return $countryId;
    }
    return parent::getCountryId();
}

/**
 * Retrieve customer region identifier
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getRegion()
{
    if (null !== ($region = $this->getFormData()->getRegion())) {
        return $region;
    } elseif (null !== ($region = $this->getFormData()->getRegionId())) {
        return $region;
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * Newsletter module availability
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function isNewsletterEnabled()
{
    return $this->_moduleManager->isOutputEnabled('Magento_Newsletter');
}

/**
 * Restore entity data from session
 * Entity and form code must be defined for the form
 *
 * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\Form $form
 * @param string|null $scope
 * @return $this
 */
public function restoreSessionData(\Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\Form $form, $scope = null)
{
    if ($this->getFormData()->getCustomerData()) {
        $request = $form->prepareRequest($this->getFormData()->getData());
        $data = $form->extractData($request, $scope, false);
        $form->restoreData($data);
    }

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get minimum password length
 *
 * @return string
 * @since 100.1.0
 */
public function getMinimumPasswordLength()
{
    return $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(AccountManagement::XML_PATH_MINIMUM_PASSWORD_LENGTH);
}

/**
 * Get number of password required character classes
 *
 * @return string
 * @since 100.1.0
 */
public function getRequiredCharacterClassesNumber()
{
    return $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(AccountManagement::XML_PATH_REQUIRED_CHARACTER_CLASSES_NUMBER);
}


public function postdata()
{
    $radioVal = $_POST["Hello"];
    var_dump($radioVal);
    die("ttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt");

    if ($radioVal == "male") {

       // set the group customer to local

        $group = $this->groupRepository->getById(4);
        return  $group->getCode();


    }elseif($radioVal == "female") {

        //set the group customer to export
        $group = $this->groupRepository->getById(5);
        return  $group->getCode();




    }
}
```

}

and here is the code of my `newcustomer.phtml`

```
<?php if ($block->getRegistration()->isAllowed()): ?>
    <div class="block block-new-customer">
        <div class="block-title">
            <strong id="block-new-customer-heading" role="heading" aria-level="2"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('New Customers')) ?></strong>
        </div>
        <div class="block-content" aria-labelledby="block-new-customer-heading">
            <p><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Creating an account has many benefits: check out faster, keep more than one address, track orders and more.')) ?></p>
            <div class="actions-toolbar">
                <div class="primary">
                    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $block->getBaseUrl().'Mweb/Inscription/Block/Form/Register' ?>" >
                        <input type="radio" name="hello" value="male" checked> Client Local<br>
                        <input type="radio" name="hello" value="female"> Client Export<br>
                        <a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getCreateAccountUrl()) ?>" class="action create primary"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Create an Account')) ?></span></a>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
<?php endif; ?>`
```

and then according to the result of `postdata()` function I test and show the form in the `Register.phtml`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here is the basic idea, you need to use this customer class in your construct

> \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer

like this-

```
protected $customer;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customer
)
{
    $this->customer = $customer;
}

....
....

public yourfunction()
{
   $customerId = "1";
   $customer = $this->customer->load($customerId);
   $customer->setData('group_id', 3)->save(); // 3 is group id whatever you want to set
}
```

I hope this will help, please write in comments after follow up.

Comment: so i have to put this code in Register.php  ??? the problem is that i will show a different form in register.phtml according to the button radio chosen and then save this customer with a customer group chosen

Comment: I hope that you understand me and thanks for your replay

Comment: yes, you need to put this code in your `register.php` file where you want to set group_id of that customer.

Comment: so i have to test $radioVal = $_POST["Hello"]; and if         if ($radioVal == "male") {
your code }else {} but i do'nt know the Customer Id ??? it'is not 1

Comment: yes, can you please paste your all code of `Register.php`?

Comment: can you please check my update question and thanks

Comment: ok..is your function `postdata()` working correct and giving you what you want?

Comment: no no result as if i did nothing :(

Comment: I created a new module : overrided the Block Register.php and the layout default.xml <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\RegisterLink" name="register-link" template="Mdweb_Inscription::form/register.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Create an Account</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>

Comment: and tthen i overrided the template register.phtm

Comment: then i create a the magento_Customer and oerrided the template newcustomer.phtml